# Does column store index affect the amount of memory needed for inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, columnstore

I have a table with over 700M rows. I have tried 2 different indexing options: 1) 1 clustered and 1 non clustered index 2) one clustered column store index.

I am using SQL Server 2016.

When using the first option, I was able to join this table with another table in about 30 minutes.

With the second option I received an Out of Memory error after about 35 minutes.

Is it possible that this out of memory error was connected to the use of Column Store index? Or is it more likely that the server was just busy? If it is some feature of the column store index, is there a way to avoid this error?

Additionally, are there some instances (when you have more than 100,000,000 rows) when the usual index is preferred to the column store?

EDIT:

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
    column1 (bigint, not null),
    column2 (int, not null),
    column3 (bigint, not null),
    column4 (int, not null),
    column5 (datetime, not null),
    column6 (date, not null),
    column7 (datetime, not null),
    column8 (tinyint, not null),
    column9 (int, not null),
    column10 (datetime, not null),
    column11 (date, null)
)
```

There are no keys defined.

Indexing option 1:

```
create clustered index index1 on table1
    (column8, column1)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index2 on table1(column4,column11)
    INCLUDE(
     column2
      ,column6
      ,column7
      )
```

Indexing option 2:

```
create clustered columnstore index colindex1 on table1
```

The Join:

```
SELECT table1.column1
      ,table1.column2
      ,table1.column3
      ,table1.column4
      ,table1.column5
      ,table1.column6
      ,table1.column7
      ,table1.column8
      ,table1.column10
      ,table1.column11
      ,table2.column4
      ,table2.column5
      ,table2.column6
      ,table2.column7
      ,table2.column8
      ,table2.column9
      INTO newTable
      FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
    ON (table1.column1 = table2.column1 and
        table1.column11 = table2.column2 and
        table1.column8 = table2.column3);
```

Comment: We need a lot more info. Show the table definition, the query you are using for your join, execution plans, and index definitions.

Comment: If the query is accessing all the columns in the table, then it is quite possible that the columnstore index uses more space -- because it needs both the compressed and uncompressed versions of the index.  That is just speculation, however.  Your question doesn't have much information on what is actually running.

Comment: @dfundako thanks, working on it now

Answer (score 0):

First, try and come up with a primary key. If you can define a unique set of columns, there is nothing that beats that indexing. If you cannot do that, create a clustered index on `column1, column8 and column11` (all the columns used in the join clause). Then if you have other select statements, see what columns are used in joins and where clauses and you can add additional non-clustered indices for them as well.